# How do I answer a video call request in Empathy?

Tags: video, empathy

My friend sent me a video call request on his phone (Gtalk) to myself (using Empathy).  I heard a ringing  noise and a notification of the call, but I have no way of answering the call!

I looked in the envelope indicator but there was nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be working

From [here](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/FAQ#Does_Empathy_support_audio_and_video_chat_with_Google_Talk.3F)

> Does Empathy support audio and video chat with Google Talk?
>
> Yes, you can have a audio or video chat on the Gtalk protocol with someone using Gmail's video chat feature, Empathy or Pidgin.

Note that if your contact is using Google Video, be sure he has the latest version of the plugin which can be downloaded from [this page](http://www.google.com/chat/video).

If it is not working, you should probably file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Eventually found out that when a computer is ringing, little letter icon becomes green so left click on it, a drop down menu appears with a person who is calling as a new entry, so right click on that person. A new window appears asking: "This person is calling you, would you like to answer?"

Hope this helps.